# Taxpayers can opt for their total income from employment or other sources to be assessed on an aggregate basis as under salaries tax?

Tags: taxes, hong-kong

I freelance in HK. I found this paragraph in a letter from Hong Kong's Inland Revenue Department. They didn't embold anything, I embolded all the jargon I don't understand. Can someone translate all this to simple English? What the heck does "aggregate basis" mean? "same manner as under salaries tax"? Thank you.

> Personal assessment allows taxpayers to **opt for their total income
> from employment, or other sources**, to be assessed on **an aggregate
> basis in the same manner as under salaries tax.** This enables a
> taxpayer to take the following advantages:
>
> (a) to completely enjoy personal allowances
>
> (b) to deduct approved charitable donations of not more than 35% of
> total income
>
> (c) to deduct interest expenses on money borrowed for producing
> taxable property rental income
>
> (d) and to offset tax losses sustained under one source of income,
> against other sources of income.